# Thunderbolt Dock to PC Motherboard on Type-C

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard

I have a Thunderbolt dock to connect my work laptop to monitors, keyboard, and mouse.

I am planning to build a personal PC and use the same setup.

I know the Thunderbolt and Type-C are different, but Type-C 3.2 still supports decent bandwidth, and there are a few Type-C docks on Amazon.

I was wondering if I could connect my Thunderbolt dock to the Type-C port on PC's motherboard and get the setup working the same as the laptop.

1. Since the Thunderbolt dock is meant to deliver 90-130W power to my laptop, will it fry my Motherboard? I see that the power delivery is a negotiated protocol and it does not happen unless the receiver asks for it, so is it something I can at least try without burning the board?
2. How does it all play with the Graphic card in the picture, since it is supposed to drive the displays?
3. I have a feature called "PCIE Tunneling over USB4" on the BIOS settings, does it have anything to do with this?

Comment: In order to transmit video over Type-C it must either support TB4 or support Alt Mode most desktop graphic cards don’t support either

Comment: No, PCIE Tunneling over USB4, won’t help in this case.

Comment: Is it best to use a KVM switch then to connect to either of the machines